# Testing palindrome with nested loops

Tags: python, palindrome

I understand that this is the easiest and most simplest way to check:

```
if val == val[::-1]:
    print "yes"
else:
    print "no"
```

but just for practice, I wanted to test it with nested for loops (using the `reversed()` function -- I spent hours but couldn't quite figure where to `continue` and `break` to get it right:

```
for i in val:
    for j in reversed(val):
        if i == j:
            break
    break
```

Comment: Why are you comparing each letter of the word with every letter of the palindrome?

Comment: `val[::-1]` <-> `str(reversed(val))`

Comment: @jamylak cause I want to learn continue/break. I want to use for loop inside for loop for this excercise.

Comment: @Nimbuz This is not a good exercise to use a nested loop since each letter of the word needs to only compare with one other letter.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think you mean `''.join(reversed(val))`

Comment: To avoid `break`/`continue` hassles, just make it a function and `return` where appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should do it:

```
for i, j in zip(val, reversed(val)):
    if i != j:
        print 'no'
        break
else:
    print 'yes'
```

**EDIT:** many thanks to @jamylak for pointing out the `else` clause on `for` loops. I keep forgetting that!

But then, I'd probably just do:

```
print 'yes' if list(val) == list(reversed(val)) else 'no'
```

Comment: To print yes with this for loop and an `else` to the for loop. Alternatively you can use `all(i==j for i,j in zip(text,reversed(text)))`

Comment: Using a for/else seems like intentional obfuscation.

Comment: @sneak, but the OP already had the one true way to do it. he's looking for a more cumbersome approach ;)

Comment: @sneak Yeah a lot of Pythonistas don't like `for`/`else`

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(len(val)/2):
    if val[i] != val[-i-1]:
        return False
return True
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a usecase of nested loops. Nested loops are useful when you want to compare each element of something with each element of something else.
In your case you only want to compare the first position with the last, the second with the second last and so on.
You need to do this:

```
for i in range(len(val)/2):
    if val[i] != val[-i-1]:
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Comment: It is the same as the above answer and that should be given preference as the correct answer.. I have simply used it to show continue and break and also explain why nested loops are not apt